# Why is my camera so far from rendered model?

Tags: three.js, blender

I am trying to create my first glTF model in Three.js rendered from Blender and I can not get the camera to display close to the rendered model.

No matter what I do to the Blender camera nothing fixes the problem so it must be the code that has been written in Three.js. Please help! Thx

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>three.js webglTF - loader</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no,         
    minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Monospace;
            background-color: #000;
            color: #fff;
            margin: 0px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        #info {
            color: #fff;
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            z-index: 100;
            display:block;
        }
        #info a {
            color: #046;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <script src="../build/three.js"></script>

    <script src="js/libs/inflate.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>

    <script src="js/WebGL.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        if ( WEBGL.isWebGLAvailable() === false ) {

            document.body.appendChild( WEBGL.getWebGLErrorMessage() );

        }

        var container, stats, controls;
        var camera, scene, renderer, light;

        var clock = new THREE.Clock();

        var mixers = [];

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {

            container = document.createElement( 'div' );
            document.body.appendChild( container );

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / 
            window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );
            camera.position.set( -400, 0, 200 );

            controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
            controls.target.set( 0, 0, 0 );
            controls.update();

            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xa0a0a0 );
            scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0xa0a0a0, 200, 1000 );

            light = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xffffff, 0x444444 );
            light.position.set( 0, 200, 0 );
            scene.add( light );

            light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
            light.position.set( 0, 200, 100 );
            light.castShadow = true;
            light.shadow.camera.top = 180;
            light.shadow.camera.bottom = -100;
            light.shadow.camera.left = -120;
            light.shadow.camera.right = 120;
            scene.add( light );

            // scene.add( new THREE.CameraHelper( light.shadow.camera ) 
            );

            // ground
            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 
            2000, 2000 ), new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { material: 
            0x999999, depthWrite: false } ) );
            mesh.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;
            mesh.receiveShadow = true;
            scene.add( mesh );

            var grid = new THREE.GridHelper( 2000, 20, 0x000000, 0x000000 
            );
            grid.material.opacity = 0.2;
            grid.material.transparent = true;
            scene.add( grid );

            // model
            var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();

            loader.load( '../The-Raisin/TREE_GLTF.gltf', function ( gltf) 
{

            scene.add( gltf.scene );

            }, undefined, function ( error ) {

            console.error( error );

        } );

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

            // stats
            stats = new Stats();
            container.appendChild( stats.dom );

        }

        function onWindowResize() {

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        }

        //

        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );

            if ( mixers.length > 0 ) {

                for ( var i = 0; i < mixers.length; i ++ ) {

                    mixers[ i ].update( clock.getDelta() );

                }

            }

            renderer.render( scene, camera );

            stats.update();

        }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Camera is displayed outside of scene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No matter what I do to the Blender camera nothing fixes the problem

Changing the camera properties in Blender has not effect if you define an own camera object in your application. You have two options:

- Access `gltf.cameras` in your `onLoad()` callback which represents an array of cameras defined in the `glTF` asset. If the camera from Blender is exported, you should find it right there.
- Improve the parameters of the camera defined in your application with an approach similar to 3D viewers. You usually center your object first and then derive optimal camera parameters from the object's AABB. Try to use the following code from this `three.js` based `glTF` viewer:

https://github.com/donmccurdy/three-gltf-viewer/blob/18f43073bbfdbd3c220e2059e548e74c507522d2/src/viewer.js#L218-L246

`three.js R104`

Comment: The direction you gave me worked. Thx for your help!